# Postgre SQL.Копирование столбцов из одной таблицы в другую с условием

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне необходимо скопировать значения одной таблицы в другую с условием,т.е. есть таблица с матаданными полей таблиц (назовем её `meta_fields`)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и с метаданными таблицы (назовем её `meta_tables`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и нужно скопировать `meta_tables.id`  в `meta_fields.id_table` , `где meta_tables.name = meta_fields.table_name`.

**UPD 1**
Пробовал такой запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как записи уже существуют, то их надо не добавлять insert а изменять update. https://makandracards.com/makandra/32357-postgresql-vs-mysql-how-to-update-using-a-join

Comment: @Mike а есть возможность получить системные айдишники таблиц и полей? просто мне необходимо на странице создать возможность переключаться между справочниками, который выбираются из select. т.е. выбран справочник, жмакаем кнопочку, отправляется запрос с id таблицы, получаем таблицу с полями, отрисовываем таблицу на странице с данными

Comment: нет у них никаких доступных id. в любом случае надо вести свой перечень "справочников", потому как таблиц в БД гораздо больше чем стоило бы отображать

Comment: @Mike понял, большое спасибо, разместите первый комментарий как ответ, я его помечу как решение